# List<T>.Add() does not add the elements in order?

Tags: c#, list, insert, addition

I have a `List<OrderItem> orderItems` that contains all the items from the database for the batch of orders I'm working on.
I also have a `Dictionary<int, Order> order_list` that contains the orders the items need to go in.
The Order object has a `List<OrderItem>` member named OrderItems.

I have an Order with an ID of 1 in order_list.
I have three items in OrderItems that carry the order_id of 1 with three different product variant id's.

The fetch from the database retrieves the items in the order of the product variant id.  This means that orderItems looks something like this:

> [0] => orderId = 1, productVariantId = 4
>  [1] => orderId = 1,
>   productVariantId = 5
>  [2] => orderId = 1, productVariantId = 6

In my code I have a loop that goes through the orderItems and assigns them to their respective orders:

```
foreach (OrderItem orderItem in orderItems)
{
    if (order_list.ContainsKey(orderItem.OrderId))
    {
        order_list[orderItem.OrderId].OrderItems.Add(orderItem);
    }
}
```

After the loop executes, I find the OrderItems member for order 1 looks like this:

> [0] => orderId = 1, productVariantId = 5
>  [1] => orderId = 1,
>   productVariantId = 6
>  [2] => orderId = 1, productVariantId = 4

I stepped through the code carefully and watched it insert the elements.  Here is what I saw it do:

Iteration 1 for product variant 4, the final OrderItems looked like this:

> [0] => orderId = 1, productVariantId = 4

Iteration 2 for product variant 5, the final OrderItems looked like this:

> [0] => orderId = 1, productVariantId = 5
>  [1] => orderId = 1,
>   productVariantId = 4

Iteration 3 for product variant 6, the final OrderItems looked like this:

> [0] => orderId = 1, productVariantId = 5
>  [1] => orderId = 1,
>   productVariantId = 6
>  [2] => orderId = 1, productVariantId = 4

My research has led me to conclude this should not be behaving such because the `List<T>.Add()` method should always add the new element to the END of the list.
Can anyone tell me why the `List<T>.Add()` does not add the elements in order in my application?

Comment: look into .Insert() instead of add() Insert is overloaded and you can specificy where to insert

Comment: Because the framework can never determine properly what's your correct order.

Comment: Are you sure the type for the `OrderItems` property of the `Order` class is `List<T>`?

Comment: `List` doesn't have a `ContainsKey` method, which leads me to believe `order_list` is a `Dictionary<int, Orders>`.  Can you confirm that?  (That's an important detail here.)  (Note that calling something that's really a dictionary a list is very confusing.)  Also confirm the type of the key, is it `int`, or a custom type?  (I'm skeptical that it's `int`.)  Also, please show the code that's displaying your results.

Comment: What you're seeing is impossible based on the information you've given us. Hence, there must be some important information you have not included. Can you post a more complete sample (ideally, something we can compile and run to duplicate your results)?

Comment: @user1886461 `insert` won't change what's going on here.  `Add` always adds items to the end of the list, which is what you want.  Clearly there's quite a bit of important information you haven't included, and your problem most likely has nothing at all to do with any `List`.  Providing the information I asked for would go a long way towards allowing us to try to effectively help you.  As it is, we're in the dark.

Comment: @Cumbayah: You didn't read to the end of my post.

Comment: @juan.facorro: private List<OrderItem> order_items = new List<OrderItem>();

Comment: @Servy: Dictionary<int, Order> order_list = new Dictionary<int, Order>(); My bad.

Comment: @user1886461 - Well there's your problem then. It's not a List, it's a Dictionary which doesn't preserve order of insertion.

Comment: @user1886461 Okay, now we're still missing the code for how you're displaying the result (so we know what we're looking at).  You should also include the code that populates the dictionary initially.

Comment: @SystemDown No, it doesn't.  He at least thinks that the dictionary just has one key, and the value of that key has a property with a list, and that list should have all of the order items.  Those *should* be ordered.

Comment: Correct.  The dictionary is where the orders are.  The problem is the order of insertion of the orderItems which do go into a list.  Maybe this will shed some light on it: 

http://screencast.com/t/dC5TYV96Bt

Comment: So far as I can tell, it displays the data in the order it's saving them here.  I fail to see how my method of displaying them will affect how this sorts.

Comment: @user1886461 It would mostly matter if you weren't properly representing what the list actually had when you displayed it.

Comment: @Servy I appreciate your advice. I checked that first and have traced the problem back to this step here.

Comment: I can't see where the problem is. It would be really sensational if the true reason was the `List<T>.Add(T)` inserted in the middle of the list (instead of appending). Can you show us the definition of the `Order` type (`class`?) and its property/field `OrderItems`? I think you should try to "boil down" your problem to a short but complete program that still has the wrong behavior, because it is difficult for us to debug your full application.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen http://pastebin.com/ecmReUq5  To be perfectly honest, I'm not sure I could duplicate this program in a reasonable time frame even in such a simple manner.  I have almost no .NET training.  I'm trying to modify this code for my employer but I normally rock the PHP.

Comment: Nothing unusual there. I really can't believe the order (pun?) of the items is not preserved.

Comment: As others have said, List<T>.Add() does append to the end.  There's not enough information here to tell you what you're doing wrong though.  Can you write a minimal, self-contained program that demonstrates what you think the problem is?

Comment: I'm afraid that will limit the quality of responses that you get.

Comment: here is my output: http://screencast.com/t/4qu3nnFG3J

Comment: A vid I made of my debugging process.  See if you can spot my mistake(s):http://screencast.com/t/Utt4gcoi

Comment: So, in absence of a clear answer, I went ahead and brute forced a solution for myself by removing the .Add() in favor of a .Insert().  With a little clever manipulation, I have a simple bubble sort working.

Answer (score 2):

The first line in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) docs says "Adds an object to the end of the List<T>", so yes, order is maintained.  You have a lot more going on in your code than simple list manipulation, but your sample is not complete enough to tell you what your mistake is.

Comment: Thank you so much for re-iterating a point I included in my initial post.</sarcasm>

Comment: You are free to ignore it, but it answers the stated question of "List<T>.Add() does not add the elements in order?"  I'd like to be more helpful, but I'm afraid this question does not currently have a better answer.

Comment: I wrote "My research has led me to conclude this should not be behaving such because the List<T>.Add() method should always add the new element to the END of the list." And then followed it up with the question  "Can anyone tell me why the List<T>.Add() does not add the elements in order in my application?"  This answer fails to address the question.

Answer (score 1):

I find that question does not provide enough code. Since I cannot comment, here is my interpretation, via LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    //populate
    var dbOrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
    dbOrderItems.Add(new OrderItem { OrderId = 1, ProductVariantId = 4 });
    dbOrderItems.Add(new OrderItem { OrderId = 1, ProductVariantId = 5 });
    dbOrderItems.Add(new OrderItem { OrderId = 1, ProductVariantId = 6 });
    dbOrderItems.Add(new OrderItem { OrderId = 2, ProductVariantId = 10 });
    dbOrderItems.Add(new OrderItem { OrderId = 2, ProductVariantId = 11 });
    dbOrderItems.Dump();

    Dictionary<int, Order> order_list = new Dictionary<int, Order>();
    foreach(OrderItem orderItem in dbOrderItems)
    {
        if (order_list.ContainsKey(orderItem.OrderId))
        {
            var currOrderItems = order_list[orderItem.OrderId].OrderItems;
            if (currOrderItems.Contains(orderItem) == false)
            {
                // order exists, add new order item
                currOrderItems.Add(orderItem);
                order_list[orderItem.OrderId].OrderItems = currOrderItems; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // new order
            order_list.Add(orderItem.OrderId, new Order { OrderId = orderItem.OrderId, OrderItems = new List<OrderItem> { orderItem } });
        }
    }

    order_list.Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
    public int ProductVariantId {get;set;}
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems {get;set;}
}
```

Output for Order 1:

```
OrderId ProductVariantId 
1 4 
1 5 
1 6
```

Output for Order 2:

```
OrderId ProductVariantId 
2 10 
2 11
```

Now, what was the question?

Comment: The question is, when I run a similar code, the output for the first orderId is:
1 5<br>
1 6<br>
1 4<br>

Comment: Can you post your abbreviated code, so I can run it? I tried few different changes and print options and I always get `1 4` `1 5` `1 6`.

Comment: You can find all of this in the discussion under the original post.